# .NET WebAPI not parsing [FromBody] properly from request content

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm used to the flow of HTTP content negotiation but something seems out of place with the following:

I have a .NET WebApi controller with the following content:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Search for Records corresponding to the given criterias
    /// </summary>
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SearchRecord([FromBody]SearchPeopleModel recordSearchModel)
    {
        var recordService = Context.Services.Get<IRecordService>();
        var result = await recordService.SearchRecord(recordSearchModel);
        return Jsonify(result);
    }
```

Using Fiddler, the request content is as follow:

```
POST http://localhost:43465/api/Record/SearchRecord HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:43465
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 72
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json
Origin: (hidden)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:43465/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=(hidden)

{"Any":"mat","Firstname":"","Lastname":"","Birthname":"","PatientId":""}
```

The resulting recordSearchModel is NULL when debugging the WebApi.
I've to tried to play with body content and JSON.stringify/not and this does not appear to be the problem either.

I must be missing something but... I can't see where ! Hope someone can help !

**EDIT**: as request here the searchPeopleModel class. I won't show the implementation of RecordService as it has nothing to do with the question here.

```
public class SearchPeopleModel
{
    public string Any {get; set;}
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Birthname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? PatientId { get; set; }
}
```

Some precision as i may have been unclear: the recordSearchModel is null when ASP.NET WEB API receives the request, the rest of the code acts perfectly as intended.

Comment: Can you provide the RecordService code.

Comment: same with different model class, code is works for me.

Comment: can you show the SearchPeopleModel class?

Comment: As requested, EDIT added with searchPeopleModel class impementation

Comment: Still its working for me

Answer (score 0):

I finally dig this out.

It appears the parameter

```
public Guid? PatientId { get; set; }
```

From SearchPeopleModel cannot be deserialized by default by asp.net webapi.
For such behavior to work we must send:

```
{"Any":"mat","Firstname":"","Lastname":"","Birthname":""}
```

Instead of:

```
{"Any":"mat","Firstname":"","Lastname":"","Birthname":"","PatientId":""}
```

Cause:
"" cannot bu turned into a valid null Guid.
"[some-valid-guid]" works though.

Hope it can help someone.